# Python SQLite3 UPDATE performance

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, database-performance

Why does `WHERE index = ?` run more quickly than `WHERE prop_link = ?`

Imagine the following table:

Name: addresses

Columns: idx (INTEGER PRIMARY KEY), full_street (TEXT), prop_link (TEXT)

Length: 100 million rows

Now imagine the following two lines of code.

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE addresses SET full_street = ? WHERE prop_link = ?", (street_var, property_link_var))

cursor.execute("UPDATE addresses SET full_street = ? WHERE idx = ?", (street_var, idx_var))
```

I have had to deal with this table a lot over the past few days.

For several of those days I was stuck because my code was freezing on the 'WHERE prop_link = ?' line and even waiting for an hour, it wouldn't unfreeze and I couldn't figure out why.

When I tried using the 'WHERE idx = ?' line, surprisingly, my code began completing in fractions of a millisecond.

Why is that? I have looked at https://sqlite.org/queryplanner.html and https://sqlite.org/optoverview.html and https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#connection-objects and maybe I missed it, but I wasn't able to find why the speed-up is so drastic.

My guess is either some type of hash-map or a binary search, but I want to be able to better understand it so I can write performant code (100 million rows).

Comment: Does the `idx` column contain all unique values? If so, then the code only has to run the update for that occurrence, however, if `prop_link` is not unique, then there could be potentially millions of rows to update.

Comment: @JohnGordon: It's the primary key, I would imagine it's indexed.

Comment: `idx` is the primary key, therefore it is indexed.  Presumably `prop_link` is not indexed, which explains the difference in speed.

Comment: @JohnGordon @Ajax1234 `idx` is the primary key, indexed, and unique. `prop_link` is unique, but is not indexed.

Comment: @Query there is your answer.  an indexed column will always perform faster than an unindexed one.